# Не отображатся картинки в android при преобразовании xml файлов

Tags: android, xslt

Не отображатся картинки в android при преобразовании xml файлов

Comment: Так <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@xlink:href,'#')"/>, которое вы закомментировали выводит что-нибудь в андроиде?

Comment: Нет ничего ...

Comment: Пишу ответом, так как комменты почему то не работают. Это будета так:

    <xsl:template match="fb:image" name="image" xmlns="namespace-aware=true">?

Просто с xslt первый раз столкнулся.

Answer (score 1):

Такое ощущение что трансформатор в Android'е игнорирует XML namespace. Попробуйте задать руками, что `namespace-aware=true`